# Error in assembly x86: Access violation writing location 0x0081D45C

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to put the elements from the x[] array >=10 in the vmic[] array, and the others in the vmare[] array. But it throws an error: Access violation writing location 0x0081D45C, when I want to copy the element in one array and I don't know what to do. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //I want to put the elements >=10 in the vmic[] array, and the others int the vmare[] array.
    //until the element in the array is 0
    int x[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,14,22,0 };
    int vmic[10];
    int vmare[10];
    int n = 10;
    int k1 = 0; //vmic
    int k2 = 0; // vmare
    _asm {
        mov eax, 0; //index
        lea ebx, x; 
        lea ecx, vmic; 
        lea edx, vmare; 
        mov esi, n; //val 10
    bucla:
        cmp[ebx + 4 * eax], 0;
        je afara;
        cmp[ebx + 4 * eax], esi;
        jge mai_mare_egal;
        inc k1;
        mov edi, [ebx + 4 * eax]; 
        mov[ecx + 4 * k1], edi;
    mai_mare_egal:
        inc k2;
        mov edi, [ebx + 4 * eax];
        mov[edx + 4 * k2], edi;
    inc eax;
    jmp bucla;
    afara:
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        printf("% d", x[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= k1; i++)
    {
        printf("% d", vmic[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= k2; i++)
    {
        printf("% d", vmare[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: the error]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: Now as for your post: what is your question?

Comment: Since this code shouldn't even compile, and the error mentions writing in an instruction that reads, I strongly suspect you are running a different binary.

Comment: My question is that I don't really understand why I get that error and what does it mean.

Comment: First make sure you compiled exactly the code shown without errors. An instruction that reads should never produce an error about writing.

Comment: Do you mean if I press Start without debugging,ctrl+F5? It doesn't show any error. But if I go into debug it shows like in the image. Sorry if I didn't understand clearly what you asked, I'm fairly new to assembly.

Comment: @Alina “access violation” means you have tried to access a memory location that you are not permitted to access.  For example, it could be an unmapped address.  It is likely that you had messed up your addressing somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried debugging this in VS2022, and it gets the line-numbers mixed up sometimes. Better to debug in the Disassembly window ... Also, there was some pretty weird stuff happening in the Disassembly window regarding the on-the-fly pointer arithmetic. For example, this line:

```
mov[edx + 4 * k2], edi;
```

... became this:

```
mov         dword ptr k2[edx*4],edi
```

It's been 20+ years since I last wrote assembly, but that looks weird to me. It looks like it's treating k2 as a dword array, and edx as the offset into that array ... which isn't right.

Anyway, I had a go at fixing it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //I want to put the elements >=10 in the vmic[] array, and the others int the vmare[] array.
  //until the element in the array is 0
  int x[] = { 11,2,3,4,5,14,22,0 };
  int vmic[10];
  int vmare[10];
  int n = 10;
  _asm {
    mov eax, 0; //index
    lea ecx, vmic;
    lea edx, vmare;
    mov esi, n; //val 10
  bucla:
    lea ebx, x;
    add ebx,eax
    cmp dword ptr[ebx], 0;
    je afara;
    cmp [ebx], esi;
    jge mai_mare_egal;
    mov edi, [ebx];
    mov [ecx], edi;
    add ecx,4;
    add eax, 4;
    jmp bucla;
  mai_mare_egal:
    mov edi, [ebx];
    mov [edx], edi;
    add edx,4;
    add eax, 4;
    jmp bucla;
  afara:         
    mov dword ptr [edx], 0
    mov dword ptr [ecx], 0
  }
  int i;
  for (i = 0; x[i]; i++)
    printf("% d", x[i]);
  printf("\n");
  for (i = 0; vmic[i]; i++)
    printf("% d", vmic[i]);
  printf("\n");
  for (i = 0; vmare[i]; i++)
    printf("% d", vmare[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even the disassembly window isn't showing the full story; as a local variable, `int k2` will be on the stack, not with a named symbol.  So `[k2]` will be `[ebp - constant]`; any named variable is just an address in asm.  The OP wrote code that used its address in a weird way, instead of its value, so yeah, offsetting from it like it was an array even though it's not.

Comment: It's very weird that MSVC would compile `[edx + k2*4]` at all, especially applying the scale factor to the other register.  Hopefully it at least warns about that, but MSVC inline asm support is pretty brittle and flaky, apparently so unmaintainable that they just made it unsupported for 64-bit.  So I could totally imagine that it sees the `* 4` and applies it to the named register instead of getting `[edx + ebp*4 - constant*4]`, not that that would work or make sense, but it's what you might get for a real assembler with `k2` as a text macro for `ebp-8` or something.

Comment: Anyway yes, as usual the right way is to keep loop counters in registers, not memory, where you can use them in addressing modes.